# For loop array set element equal to a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, element, getelementsbyname

In the application a csv or xlsx file is parsed and the user then selects which fields represent an address.

[image: Field Selection]

After that I put the entire csv into an array and start to loop through it to send the address to be geocoded. The issue that I am having is that I need a way to set the array element equal to the field the user selected.

Before I loop through the array I grab the selection from each of the dropdowns like so.

```
var address_selection = document.getElementsByName("address1")[0].value;
var address2_selection = document.getElementsByName("address2")[0].value;
var city_selection = document.getElementsByName("city")[0].value;
var state_selection = document.getElementsByName("state")[0].value;
var postalcode_selection = document.getElementsByName("postalcode")[0].value;
```

My current code is setup like this, which hard codes the variable equal to a specific element.

```
for (i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        var id = output.ID;
        var address = output[i].Address;
        var address2 = output[i].Address2;
        var city = output[i].City;
        var state = output[i].StateProvince;
        var postalcode = output[i].ZipPostalcode;
```

What I need to do is somehow keep the variable names the same but change the element based on the user selection. I have tried something like this but it does not work.

```
var address = ("output[i]." + address_selection);
```

Comment: Do you want something like `output[i].address_selection` or `output[i][address_selection]` ?

Comment: output[i].address_selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference array indexes and object properties using `[]` notation, so in JS, this is very easy.

In your case, it looks like `output` is an array of objects, so `output[i]` is an object with fields like `Address`, `Address2` etc. Instead of writing `output[i].Address` you can write it as `output[i]["Address"]`. Furthermore, `"Address"` can be replaced with a variable just like `i`.

With that in mind, and assuming the values of the options in your dropdownlists are things like "Address" and "Address2" then you should just be able to write this:

```
var address_selection = document.getElementsByName("address1")[0].value;
var address2_selection = document.getElementsByName("address2")[0].value;
var city_selection = document.getElementsByName("city")[0].value;
var state_selection = document.getElementsByName("state")[0].value;
var postalcode_selection = document.getElementsByName("postalcode")[0].value;

for (i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    var id = output.ID;
    var address = output[i][address_selection];
    var address2 = output[i][address2_selection];
    var city = output[i][city_selection];
    var state = output[i][state_selection];
    var postalcode = output[i][postalcode_selection];
```

Comment: @mkeller Glad you got that sorted! If you want to mark this as the accepted answer, just click the tick beneath the voting box.

Answer (score 1):

```
var address_selection = document.getElementsByName("address1")[0].value;
var address2_selection = document.getElementsByName("address2")[0].value;
var city_selection = document.getElementsByName("city")[0].value;
var state_selection = document.getElementsByName("state")[0].value;
var postalcode_selection = document.getElementsByName("postalcode")[0].value;
var myArray = {
    address_selection: address_selection,
    address2_selection: address2_selection,
    city_selection: city_selection,
    state_selection: state_selection,
    postalcode_selection: postalcode_selection
    };
for (var key in myArray) {
  console.log("key " + key + " has value " + myArray[key]);
}
```